# Change ForeColor of labels with single Timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

Can i change my ForeColor of labels with a single timer ?
I tried this method but i Don't know why just my first label become red.
this is my code :

```
        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        if (timer1.Interval == 3499)
        {
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        if(timer1.Interval == 3500)
        {
            label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        if(timer1.Interval == 4199)
        {
            label2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

How can i change my forecolor with single timer ??

Comment: Any reason why you didn't choose to use a background worker?

Comment: What you mean ? im so newbie in C# in just started to code and programming. and dont know so many about this program. and i myself trying to learning and ask my questions here

Comment: @VorTex.Zerg - You can happily user a `Timer` to do this, but it looks like you may have confused the purpose of the `Interval` property. Check out Luaan's answer below.

Comment: Also, what sort of application is this? I am guessing WinForms, but could be wrong.

Comment: it is windows form

Comment: OK, I've added a _winforms_ tag to your question.

Answer (score 6):

`Interval` is a setting of `Timer`, not the amount of time elapsed since the last time (What would that even mean in your scenario? Should the timer magically track three different intervals just because you ask for those in your code?). You set it to the frequency you want the timer to try and give you the `Elapsed` event.

For more information, check the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).